# Codeigniter Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

How can I make a wildcard subdomain with codeigniter? I have try anything on google and this site. But it wont work, if not 500 error page it will return nothing (I mean no effect) because I got this on my .htaccess before :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]  
</IfModule>
```

I think it always conflict with that one above, btw what I desired to be is :

```
example.com/page => example.com/page (without subdomain will just be normal, with no www and no index.php)
abc.example.com => example.com/abc-channel
exc.example.com => example.com/exc-channel
abc.example.com/my/foo/page => example.com/abc-channel/my/foo/page
```

All will generated with no redirect.

Comment: do you want to redirect the user to specific sub-domain

Comment: Yes, redirect without changing URL?